# incorrect answers for quadratic equations

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why my python code for solving quadratic equations isn't working. I have looked through it and haven't found any errors.

```
print("This program will solve quadratic equations for you")

print("It uses the system 'ax**2 + bx + c'")

print("a, b and c are all numbers with or without decimal \
points")

print("Firstly, what is the value of a?")

a = float(input("\n\nType in the coefficient of x squared"))

b = float(input("\n\nNow for b. Type in the coefficient of x"))

c = float(input("\n\nGreat. now what is the c value? The number alone?"))

print("The first value for x is " ,(-b+(((b**2)-(4*a* c))* * 0.5)/(2*a)))

print("\n\nThe second value for x is " ,(-b-(((b * * 2)-(4*a*c))** 0.5)/(2*a)))
```

When a=1 b=-4 and c=-3 I am expecting -1 and 4 but get 5.5 and 0.5

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Also, what is the expected output and what are you obtaining instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback guys! really encouraging to know that people are interested in helping.

So what happened is when

    a=1
    b=-3
and
    c=-4
I am expecting to get -1 and 4 but I get 5.5 and 0.5

Comment: @MichaelDunwoody Try just typing out the minimal stuff in the python interpreter, like I showed in my answer. Then copy paste from the terminal here and explain to us what parts differ from what you want.

Comment: @CrazyCasta thanks. I copied your formula into the terminal and I got 5.5 instead of 4 again when a=1, b=-4 and c=3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your trouble is in the part that tries to do the quadratic formula:

```
(-b+(((b**2)-(4*a* c))* * 0.5)/2*a)
```

The trouble is that `*` has the same precedence as `/` so you're dividing by 2 and then multiplying by `a`. Also your parentheses are off, so I reduced the unnecessary ones and moved the wrong ones. In short, -b wasn't being put together with the square root before the division. What you want is:

```
(-b+(b**2-4*a*c)**0.5)/(2*a)
```

P.S. For the sake of asking questions, it would be better to ask in the form of something like:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 1
>>> c = 3
>>> (-b+(((b**2)-(4*a* c))* * 0.5)/2*a)
got blah, expected blam
```

Since the other printing and inputting is not to blame (which you should be able to work out fairly easily).

Comment: Also shouldn't have a space between `*` and `*` to use the `**` operator.

Comment: @khelwood Hmm, I just assumed he was posting code that was syntactically correct and that python didn't care about the space. Good catch.

Comment: Yeah I made the space because this site made the 2 bold instead of displaying both asterix'

Comment: @MichaelDunwoody If you put it inside a code block (like you did) it won't interpret it as a bold formatter.

Comment: @CrazyCasta thank you! I am still getting incorrect solutions however. The formula is (-b-(((b**2)-(4*a*c))** 0.5)/(2*a)) and I edited the question to show the error. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Yes, I just looked a little harder, your parentheses were a bit off too.

Comment: @CrazyCasta OH MY GOD THANK YOU!! I got it to work! I literally started programming yesterday and it is so encouraging that I can understand that. Have a great day and I really appreciate the help